# stacks view from my design in SwiftUI not showing correctly

Tags: swiftui

I am still learning Swift UI. However, I want to mock my UI design to show in SwiftUI but for some reason it is not quite showing it properly. Can anyone to guide me of what I have done wrong in my code that is not showing like my UI design? thanks for the help.

Here is my UI design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0wqj.jpg

Here is what I have from my code below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCkKe.jpg

Here is my code:

```
     var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                    PricingView(title: "Check-in", textColor: .white, bgColor: .purple)
                    ZStack {
                        PricingView(title: "Pillars", textColor: .black, bgColor: Color(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255))
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                    PricingView(title: "Resources", textColor: .white, bgColor: .purple)
                    ZStack {
                        PricingView(title: "Chat", textColor: .black, bgColor: Color(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255))
                    }
                }
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                    PricingView(title: "Gallery", textColor: .white, bgColor: .purple)

                    ZStack {
                        PricingView(title: "VAPA", textColor: .black, bgColor: Color(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255))
                    }
                }
                ZStack {
                    PricingView(iconName: "wand.and.rays", title: "More", textColor: .white, bgColor: Color(red: 62/255, green: 63/255, blue: 70/255))
                        .padding()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WelcomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WelcomeView()
    }
}



struct PricingView: View {

    var iconName: String?
    var title: String
    var textColor: Color
    var bgColor: Color
    var bannerText: String?

    init(iconName: String? = nil, title: String, textColor: Color, bgColor: Color, bannerText: String? = "") {
        self.iconName = iconName
        self.title = title
       self.textColor = textColor
        self.bgColor = bgColor
        self.bannerText = bannerText
    }

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            VStack {
                iconName.map {
                    Image(systemName: $0)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(textColor)
                }

                Text(title)
                    .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded))
                    .fontWeight(.black)
                    .foregroundColor(textColor)


            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)

            .padding(40)
            .background(bgColor)
            .cornerRadius(10)



        }
    }
}

struct BannerView: View {

    var messageText: String
    var offset: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        Text(messageText)
            .font(.system(.caption, design: .rounded))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(5)
            .background(Color(red: 255/255, green:183/255, blue: 37/255))
            .offset(x: 0, y: offset)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I suggest you to try this. https://iosexample.com/a-waterfall-grid-layout-view-for-swiftui/ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image: You can see my output here]Try this. You can get Pinterest like view. 
First please install this pod from here - https://github.com/paololeonardi/WaterfallGrid

In your Grid file add below code.

```
import SwiftUI
import WaterfallGrid

struct CardGridView: View {

    @State private var cards: [Card] = Generator.Cards.random()

    var body: some View {
        return WaterfallGrid((0..<cards.count), id: \.self) { index in
                   CardView(card: self.cards[index])
               }
    }
}

struct Generator {

    struct Height {
        static func random() -> [Int] {
            Array(30..<90).map { ($0) }.shuffled()
        }
    }

    struct Cards {
        static func random() -> [Card] {
            Height.random().map {
                Card(title: "\($0)", subtitle: "bjashbdahjsdajv", height: $0)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And in your Card View add this code.

```
struct CardView: View {
   let card: Card

       var body: some View {
       VStack() {
           HStack() {
               VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                   Text(card.title)
                       .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: CGFloat(card.height))
                       .layoutPriority(99)
               }
               Spacer()
           }
           .padding([.leading, .trailing, .bottom], 8)
       }
        .background(Color.yellow)
       .cornerRadius(8)
       .background(
           RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
               .stroke(Color.secondary.opacity(0.5))
       )
   }
}

struct Card {
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let height: Int
}
```

Call your CardGridView() and that's it. You can add image and customize your card view.

Comment: Do I need to create a new file called `CardGridView` ?

Comment: It's upto you. You can write in same file also but it is better if you create separate one.

Comment: thank you.  Is there a way to use it without the library, like with my HStack, VStack, .... etc.?

Comment: Currently i have not any alternative solution because it takes a lot of time to develop this kind of view with perfection.

Comment: For what you need Grid file ?There is no any Grid file or class. Can you please specify what problem are you facing?